# Quotation marks in textarea text interfere with code

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have a text area in HTML with a paragraph of text. I then have a jQuery function that looks at the text area and compares it with a paragraph defined in the function. If the two paragraphs are identical, then the text area box changes background color to green, otherwise it is red. However, the problem is that in the jQuery function the paragraph contains quotation marks that interfere with the quotation marks that identify a string. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: A snipper of my code :                                                                       $(".answerBox").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Sit down. Take out your equipment," said Mr Green in his usual grim voice. "Silently!" he shouted for emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like a regex to escape the quotation marks in the textarea's value and then compare it to an escaped string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.submit').on('click', function(){
  var text = $('textarea').val().replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/, "&apos;");
        if (text === "I said, &quot;Hello!&quot;") {
        $('textarea').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c3gathkc/

Comment: Thanks you so much! Works like a charm.

Comment: No problem at all :)